# обособление: "(,) после нажатия на комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+Enter(,)"

Tags: пунктуация

На информационных порталах в интернете пользователь, обнаруживший ошибку в статье, может выделить фрагмент и(,) после нажатия на комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+Enter(,) в появившемся окошке оставить комментарий к ошибке, который затем отправляется автору для исправления.

Answer (score 3):

*Для смыслового выделения или, наоборот, только попутного пояснения могут обособляться обстоятельства, выраженные именами существительными в косвенных падежах (обычно с предлогами)*, особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова, например: Видно, и Чичиковы, на несколько минут в жизни, обращаются в поэтов… (Гоголь); …Я отстал немного, потом, с помощью хлыста и ног, разогнал свою лошадку (Л. Толстой); И потом он встречал её в городском саду и на сквере, по нескольку раз в день (Чехов); Утром проснулся он рано, с головной болью, разбуженный шумом… (Чехов); И тишина, от времени, становилась всё зловещей (Горький); Как-то вечером, набрав белых грибов, мы, по дороге домой, вышли на опушку леса (Горький); Она выедет туда первого декабря, я ж, для приличия, хоть неделей поздней (Бунин) [Обособленные обстоятельства](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/95/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

**В Вашем примере как раз такая конструкция - обстоятельство, выраженное существительным с предлогом *после*. Можно обособить. Но и без обособления предложение будет оформлено правильно.**

Comment: Простите, ещё слово Интернет принято писать с прописной буквы.

Comment: По поводу интернета - по факту уже согласились со строчной. Явление стало обыденном, название - нарицательным.  С  остальным - согласен.

Comment: Надеюсь, что это появится и в школьных учебниках. Благодарю Вас.